# i am not getting why is the answer coming it as 5,i'll write the program below

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 int cats,dogs,others,total_pets;
 cats=10;
 dogs=43;
 others=36;
 total_pets=cats+dogs;
 printf("there are %c  total pets are",total_pets);
}
```

Comment: C'mon guys, we really don't need 7+ answers all saying the same thing.

Comment: They all came in at almost the same time.

Comment: Yep. all within a matter of few seconds. I saved my edit and boom there were 7 answers.

Comment: It's so hard to choose an answer to upvote :)

Comment: @Vic: Rather than who was first, I use "whose is the most comprehensive" as my voting criterion. I like to reward those who took the time to explain *why* the problem caused the behavior it did, rather than just providing the solution. codaddict's answer is a great example of this.

Comment: Every time someone writes `void main` a kitten dies...

Answer (score 10):

Use `%d` in place of `%c` in the `printf`.

The value of `total_pet` is `53`. When you use `%c` in `printf` you are trying to print the character whose [ASCII](http://bestofthisweb.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/ascii_table2.jpg) value if `53` which happens to be `5`.

Answer (score 4):

See here for ASCII table : http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html

And why it printing 5 :-

Actually its '5' not 5. Your code is printing character 5 not decimal 5. When you use %c to print value of an integer variable, printf convert integer value with character equivalent (as you have seen in ASCII table).

You can try this code (or you should write your own)

`void main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Printing ASCII values Table...\n\n");
    num = 1;
    while(num<=255)
    {
       // here you can see how %c and %d works for same variable
       printf("\nValue:%d = ASCII Character:%c", num, num); 
       num++;
     }
    printf("\n\nEND\n");
}`

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you formatting it as %c
Use %d

> printf("there are %d  total pets
>   are",total_pets);

Answer (score 2):

why are you using `%c`. use `%d`

```
%c single character
%d and %i both used for integer type
%u used for representing unsigned integer
%o octal integer unsigned
%x,%X used for representing hex unsigned integer
%e, %E, %f, %g, %G floating type
%s strings that is sequence of characters
```

Answer (score 2):

Because 53 is the place in the ascii chart where '5' sits.

Use %d in your printf instead.

Answer (score 2):

`%c` is the character specifier so `printf("there are %c total pets are",total_pets);` prints the ascii character with the value 53, which is the `5` character.

Answer (score 1):

%c is to print a character. Try changing it to %d for the integer value.

What you are printing is the integer value interpreted as a character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `%c` to a `%d`.